# Regex checking start of base64 encoded file

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate start of base64 string, that is sent to my php script via javascript.

This is example value: `data:text/plain;base64,YQ==`

So I want to validate that string:

```
`- starts with "data:"
 - followed by any two words separated with /
 - then there is ";"
 - and ends up with "base64,"`
```

Comment: This might help: `/data:\w+\/\w+;base64,/`

Comment: Thats good. But there should be one more rule. Right word that is separated with / can have any number of dots so it maches format like this data:image/vnd.adobe.photoshop;base64,also

Comment: Voilà: `/data:\w+\/[\w.]+;base64,/`

Answer (score 1):

Fabian nearly had it...

`~^data:\w+/[\w\.-]+;base64,~`

Don't use slash as delimiter, that way you don't have to escape the slash in the pattern.

The dot must be escaped or it will match anything.

`\w` does include the `_`.  If you don't want the underscore included, you can use `[\da-zA-Z]` instead.

The `^` requires the match to begin at the start of the string.

Per your feedback I've added hyphens to the 2nd and 3rd character classes.  When hyphens are included in a character class, they must be list first or last to avoid escaping with a slash.

It could be more precise like this:

`~^data:[\da-zA-Z]+/[\da-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[\da-zA-Z-]+)*;base64,~`

Comment: This works like a charm. I just added `^data:\w+\/[\w\.\-]+;base64`, so it also matches "-" in the second word because some mime types for file like excel have slashes inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/data:\w+\/\w+;base64,.*/", "data:text/plain;base64,YQ==") == 1 ? print("base64") : print("don't know")
```

Comment: Thats good. But there should be one more rule. Right word that is separated with / can have any number of dots so it maches format like this `data:image/vnd.adobe.photoshop;base64,also`